# Looping through a Pandas Dataframe with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

This data contains the last four weeks of data and the idea is average the Total Volume based on Day of Week and Time. for example, if the day = Monday and time = 1 am then average the total volume from the last 4 weeks.

```
  Day of Week   Time    Total Volume
0   Monday      00:00   4
1   Monday      00:30   8
2   Monday      01:00   10
3   Monday      01:30   8
4   Monday      02:00   2
```

Here is what I've tried but this seems to be not working. Ideally, I'd like to put this in a function. Or is there a better way to loop through this df?

```
for row in data:
    if row["Day of Week"] == "Monday" and row["Time"] == "00:00" :
        avg = sum(row["Total Volume"])/4
    break
```

Comment: ```df.groupby(['Day of Week', 'Time'])['Total Volume'].mean()``` should give you what your looking for. You group by both Day of week, and the time, then look at the total volume column and take the mean.

Comment: This also works thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using for loop in pandas tend to be very slow. It is often times faster to implement a simple calculation over the entire dataframe (that can leverage numpy), and then choose the day/time you want afterwards.

You can try groupby function to calculate a 4 weeks moving average of volume from the same weekday and same time.

For example:

```
df['sma_vol_4wks'] = df['volume'].groupby(level=['day_of_week','time']).rolling(window=4).mean()
```

Comment: That works! thanks!

Comment: @AliSyed please mark this as answered when it indeed solved your problem.